# How to set the value of a Vuetify text field to upper case?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to apply `text-uppercase` to the value of a `v-text-field` ?

I tried:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="lastName"
  class="text-uppercase"
  label="Name"
  outlined
/>
```

But only the label is set to upper case instead of the value, as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by setting the getter in `computed` instead of class attribute:

```
computed: {
  lastName: {
    get() {
      return this.last_name.toUpperCase()
    }
  }
}
```